# Toyota dealership charged me $469 for Brake Rotary and Brake pads replacement. Was it necessary?

Tags: toyota

I went in for 30K service for my 2016 Camry SE. After inspection Customer Representative suggested me to replace Brake Pads and clean Brake Rotary(Drum) and gave me a quote of $469. He said, "Brake pad is almost 2mm thick and Drum is rusty. According to Virginia law, it should not be less than 1mm thick". As I know little about cost, I said okay. My question is "Was he, right about suggesting the replacement? Is it the time?" Experienced people can shed some light. Thanks.

**Receipts*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/azb76.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGiOZ.jpg

Comment: Have you ever had the front brakes done? It seems odd that rears would need to be replaced before fronts. They only resurfaced the rear rotors, not replaced. Brake work is always stupidly expensive from a dealership (IMO), but this doesn't seem criminally bad. My rule of thumb has always been if you are getting brake work done it won't be less than $500. It's really a toss-up. it was going to be needed fairly soon and I don't think it was done foolishly early.

Comment: I have to agree the price itself doesn't sound out of line. The high price is why I started doing brake pad replacement myself.

Comment: Price seems a bit high for some brake pads and grinding the rotors. Dealerships always overcharge.

Comment: Pads are available to the same quality without the logo of “Fiat" etc and tend to be cheaper...

Comment: There is a reason they are called Stealerships.

Answer (score 2):

If the next service is in 20K then 2mm of pad is not likely to survive long enough... So, yes you needed the work as if the pads go to metal you need new discs and pads...

Comment: I usually service my car every 5K miles

Comment: if that is 5k of "rally" driving then same argument... and even if not 2 mm is still too low imho - Pads I change at 4mm or below because they heat up quicker degrading performance quicker...